# USSD application for the iPad 2?

Tags: applications, ios-appstore, ipad

Are there any applications that allow you to send USSD commands to your data service provider using the iPad 2?

Removing the SIM card from the iPad and inserting it into another phone to send out a USSD command just to buy more data does tend to get a bit frustrating at times.

Answer (score -2):

There's an application called QueryUSSD available on Cydia for jailbroken phones. There's an [article on iPhoneZA](http://iphoneza.co.za/2011/09/02/how-to-check-free-minutes-free-smss-data-bundle-balance-and-more-on-ipad-and-iphone-using-ussd-codes-vodacom-mtn-cell-c-virgin-8ta/) about how to use it and what kind of codes are available.

Comment: This is a direct copy-and-paste from http://iphoneza.co.za/2011/09/02/how-to-check-free-minutes-free-smss-data-bundle-balance-and-more-on-ipad-and-iphone-using-ussd-codes-vodacom-mtn-cell-c-virgin-8ta/